# Какие существуют ограничения на голосования, изменение мнения и отмену своего голоса?

Tags: поддержка, faq, голоса-против, голоса-за

Каковы ограничения на процесс голосования?

Как часто я могу голосовать? Каким образом мои голоса блокируются, когда снимается блокировка?

<sub>Перевод вопроса «[What are the limits on how I can cast, change, and retract votes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5212/274323)».</sub>

Answer (score 10):

#### Ограничения на число голосов в день

В сети Stack Exchange время считается  [UTC/GMT](http://www.dxing.com/utcgmt.htm). [Новый день начинается в 00:00:00 UTC/GMT.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27199/what-is-an-se-day-when-does-each-day-start) ([Для зарегистрированных участников](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79288/what-time-is-it) текущее время UTC отображается постоянно.)

- Процесс голосования (за вопросы и ответы; учитываются как голоса «за», так и «против»).

  - Точное количество доступных вам голосов [зависит от характера вашего голосования в течение дня](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90202/). Конкретно, существует три ограничения сверху, которые *одновременно* нужно учитывать при расчете возможных голосов.
  - 40 голосов в день для голосования за сообщения.
  - 30 голосов в день для голосования за ответы.
  - 5 голосов в день для голосования за сообщения – после того, как вы получите ваше первое уведомление «у вас осталось еще 5 голосов». Если вы достигнете предела в 25 голосов за ответы ко времени t текущего дня, и q(t) – это количество голосов, выставленных вами при голосовании за вопросы к моменту t, общее количество голосов за сообщения будет составлять не более `30 + q(t)`. Если вы выставили менее 25 голосов за ответы, проигнорируйте данный пункт.
  - Если сообщение было удалено в тот же день, когда вы за него проголосовали, вы получите голос назад. Таким образом, в действительности, вы можете проголосовать более 30 и 40 раз, соответственно.
  - Голосовать «за» могут участники с репутацией 15 и выше.
  - Голосовать «против» могут участники с репутацией не менее 125 баллов.
- [Голосование за комментарии](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18994/what-is-the-daily-comment-vote-limit)

  - Для голосования за комментарии участнику доступно 30 голосов в день.
  - Аналогично голосованию за публикации, голоса «за» комментарии могут выставлять участники с репутацией 15 и выше. Проголосовать против комментариев невозможно.
- Голосование за закрытие/повторное открытие вопросов.

  - На Stack Overflow на английском, Mathematics, Server Fault, Super User и Ask Ubuntu участнику доступно 50 голосов в день.
  - На всех остальных сайтах участнику доступно 24 голоса в день ([источник](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/87291/131713)).
  - Голосовать за закрытие и повторное открытие могут только участники с репутацией 3000 и выше (500 и выше во время открытой беты).
  - Когда у вас остается пять и менее голосов за текущий день, после каждого следующего отданного вами голоса появляется всплывающая подсказка, информирующая о количестве оставшихся голосов.
  - Если вы попытаетесь проголосовать после достижения вами дневного лимита голосов, всплывающая подсказка сообщит вам, сколько часов осталось до того момента, когда вы опять сможете голосовать.
- Голоса за удаление

  - Участнику дается возможность голосовать за удаление сообщения до пяти раз в день.
  - Дополнительно разрешается голосовать за удаление сообщений один раз на каждую тысячу баллов репутации (для участников с репутацией более 10000), максимум до 30 голосов в день.
  - Голосовать за удаление могут участники с репутацией минимум в 10000 баллов (2000 во время открытой беты).
  - Участники с репутацией минимум 10000 (2000 для открытых бета-сайтов), но не более 20000 (4000 для открытых бета-сайтов) должны подождать два дня после закрытия вопроса, чтобы голосовать за его удаление.
  - Участники с репутацией минимум 20000 (4000 для открытой беты) могут голосовать за удаление закрытых вопросов с рейтингом -3 и ниже в любое время, а также голосовать за удаление ответов с отрицательным рейтингом

#### Отмена голосов

- В общем случае, если вы проголосовали, вы не можете изменить свой голос. Но есть два исключения.

  - Первое исключение: вы можете изменить свой голос практически неограниченное число раз в течение [пятиминутного интервала](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/38759/152859) *с момента своего первоначального голосования за сообщение*. Учтите, если изменить голос ~60 раз, такая возможность блокируется.
  - Второе исключение: вы можете менять свой голос после каждой правки соответствующей публикации – [после каждого редактирования публикации](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19235/is-this-a-bug-in-voting-or-is-it-supposed-to-work-like-this) открывается окно с результатом вашего первоначального голосования.
- Чтобы просто отменить голос — т.e. аннулировать его, как если бы вы не голосовали совсем
  —, [щелкните на соответствующую стрелку еще раз](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30557/cancel-a-vote-so-that-the-tally-goes-back-to-zero-and-not-minus). В результате будут аннулированы голоса как «за», так и «против», а вы сможете вернуться к голосованию [позже](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18360/vote-too-old-to-be-changed-but-i-havent-voted/18373#18373).
- Для того, чтобы обратить голос —, т.e. изменить голос «за» на голос «против» или наоборот —, [щелкните на противоположной стрелке](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30557/cancel-a-vote-so-that-the-tally-goes-back-to-zero-and-not-minus), как обычно. Отменять перед этим действие нет необходимости.
- **Голоса за закрытие** могут быть отозваны для любого вопроса, который еще не был закрыт, если вы голосовали не очень давно, но еще раз проголосовать за закрытие вы уже не сможете, а также не сможете еще раз отозвать свой голос по поводу одного и того же вопроса.

Comment: "Не очень давно" - это сколько?

Comment: @VenZell Как я понимаю, «не очень долго» эквивалентно 5 минутам, это период так называемой [«свежей правки»](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/3295/).