# Руководство по ограничениям действий на сайте

Tags: поддержка, faq

Я заметил, что некоторые действия, например, комментирование, я могу выполнять только ограниченное количество раз за определённый промежуток времени. Очевидно, что на сайте действует ограничение, чтобы предотвратить случайное или преднамеренное злоупотребление некоторыми функциями.

Каково это ограничение и к каким функциональным возможностям оно применяется?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод «http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/»</sub>

Comment: Даже для ромбовидных действует ограничение?

Comment: @alexolut Где–то да, где–то нет. Для меня, к примеру, точно действует ограничение на публикацию вопросов и ответов.

Comment: О! Я нашёл: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3971/178988

Answer (score 8):

### [Обоснование ограничения на количество действий](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/32202)

### Комментарии

- Голосование

  - Возможность отметить тревогой 10 комментариев в день ([количество может увеличиться до 100 тревог в день](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)).
  - [30 голосов за комментарии или за их удаление в день](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238331).
  - Возможность отдавать голоса без какого-либо времени ожидания.

    [image: Comment Voting Limit reached]
- Удаление ([обрабатывается так же, как и голосование](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/14185))

  - Ограничение отсутствует.
- Добавление

  - [Три комментария за 30 секунд](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250994/throttle-comment-button-to-prevent-double-submission/251005?noredirect=1#comment819750_251005).

  [image]
- Редактирование

  - Автор комментария или модератор могут редактировать комментарии каждые 5 секунд.
    [image]
  - По прошествии 5 минут комментарии нельзя будет редактировать (неприменимо к модераторам).

### Поиск

- Заявлено, что [для ручного поиска ограничение отсутствует](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160100), но [тестирование](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/166034) показало, что ограничение составляет 30 поисковых запросов за 60 секунд (см. комментарий к ответу по приведённой ссылке).

### Вопросы

- Для участников с репутацией < 125 баллов задержка составляет [40 минут во всех сообществах](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/322265/839601).

  - Для участников, возможности которых в сообществе ограничены [системой предотвращения повторных нарушений](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234610), — один вопрос в неделю.
  - Для участников с ограниченной возможностью задавать вопросы в течение 1–7 дней, [основываясь на качестве их предыдущих вопросов](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/asking-rate-limited).
- Участнику с репутацией < 10 000  баллов необходимо подтвердить, что он не робот, если участник задаёт более одного вопроса в течение 60 секунд.
- Участнику с репутацией > 10 000 баллов необходимо подтвердить, что он не робот, если участник задаёт более одного вопроса в течение 30 секунд.
- В сообществах Stack Overflow, Super User, Server Fault и Math (не действует в остальных сообществах):

  - до 6 вопросов в день;
  - [до 50 вопросов за 30 дней](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/89217).

  > К сожалению, вы можете задать не более 50 вопросов в течение 30 дней.

### Ответы

- Для участников с репутацией < 125 баллов [время ожидания между ответами составляет 3 минуты](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/23038).
- Участнику с репутацией > 125 < 10 000 баллов необходимо подтвердить, что он не робот, если участник публикует более одного ответа в течение 60 секунд.
- Участнику с репутацией > 10 000 баллов необходимо подтвердить, что он не робот, если участник публикует более одного ответа в течение 30 секунд.
- Не более 30 000 символов в ответе.

  [image: Answer Character Limit]

### Принятие ответов

- [Время ожидания после отправки запроса на принятие ответа составляет 15 минут для всех участников сообщества](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/44099).
- [Время ожидания после отправки запроса на принятие собственного ответа составляет 48 часов для всех участников сообщества](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

  [image: Accept Time Limit]

### Редактирование

- Можно редактировать 5 собственных сообщений в день; количество увеличивается для участников с высокой репутацией (по мере роста репутации), неприменимо к ♦ модераторам.

  > Сегодня вы уже отредактировали 5 собственных сообщений, новые правки недоступны до завтра.
- Можно удалять 5 старых ответов в день, неприменимо к ♦ модераторам.
- Один участник может предложить не более [5 правок на проверку](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281202/295232) (20 для сайтов в стадии беты).
- Незарегистрированные пользователи не могут предлагать правки, если сообщение опубликовано < 10 минут назад.
- Участнику с репутацией < 10 000 баллов необходимо подтвердить, что он не робот, если участник правит более одного сообщения за 30 секунд или завершает правку менее чем через 5 секунд после ее начала.
- Участнику с репутацией < 10 000 баллов необходимо [подтвердить, что он не робот](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2293), если участник правит более одного сообщения за 10 секунд или завершает правку менее чем через 5 секунд после ее начала.
- Сохранять правку описания метки можно каждые 30 секунд.

### Отметка тревогой

- [Ограничение по количеству отметок тревогой в день меняется в зависимости от репутации](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185890).
- 5 секунд между отметками.
- 3 секунды между попытками открыть соответствующее диалоговое окно.

  [image: Flags per day]

  [image: Flag Rate Popup]

  [image: Flag Dialog Popup]

### Проверка

- [20 сообщений в очереди проверок в день](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147981), если размер очереди меньше 1000.
- [40 сообщений в очереди проверок в день](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/152233), если размер очереди равен 1000 или больше.
- Для ♦ модераторов ограничение отсутствует.

  > На сегодня у вас больше не осталось голосов за предлагаемые правки, возвращайтесь через x часов.

### Сообщения

- 1 секунда между двумя сообщениями. Реальная кривая изменения задержки представлена ниже:

  [image: Chat Throttle Curve]
- Аналогичная задержка применяется к отметкам звездами.
- Аналогичная задержка применяется к поиску.
- Для каждого участника ограничение по звездам составляет [20 звезд на чат-комнату в день](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/236370).

### Голосование

- 30 голосов в день +10 только для вопросов (если участник потратит 25 голосов на ответы, он не сможет использовать голоса, предназначенные только для вопросов. [Источник](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5213))
- Если участник голосует, а потом отменяет это действие 30 раз, такой голос блокируется.

  [image: Your vote is now locked in]

### Изменение псевдонима на сайте

- [Один раз в 30 дней](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/38180), свежая правка возможна в течение 15 минут. Неприменимо к ♦ модераторам.
- Если с момента создания учётной записи прошло менее 2 дней, участник может беспрепятственно менять псевдоним.

### Отображение общего количества голосов «за» / «против»

- [Один раз в секунду](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/35488).

  > Информацию о количестве голосов можно обновлять не чаще одного раза в секунду.

### Закрытие вопросов

- Диалоговое окно закрытия вопросов можно открывать один раз в 3 секунды.
- Каждому участнику предоставляется 50 голосов за закрытие / повторное открытие вопросов в день в сообществе SO и 24 голоса в других сообществах. [Источник](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5213/13295)

  [image: Close Dialog rate limit box]

### Удаление

- Участник может удалить 5 собственных сообщений в день.
- [5 голосов за удаление](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/105876) (при 10 000 баллов репутации) и дополнительный голос за каждую 1000 баллов репутации свыше 10 000, максимально 30 голосов в день.
- Если вопрос задан менее 2–х дней назад, участники не могут голосовать за его удаление. [Это можно сделать только при наличии более 20 000 баллов репутации](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70044) или если рейтинг вопроса [-3 или ниже](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177675).

### Шляпы

- Можно менять каждые 10 секунд.

  [image]

### Приложение для iOS

- В связи с ограничениями API задержка между действиями составляет одну секунду. 
  [image]

Comment: почему сообщения об ошибках не переведены?

Comment: @Grundy видимо, участники стесняются совершенных ошибок и не жалуются )

Comment: @Nofate, я имел ввиду в ответе :-) потому что сами сообщения вроде как уже переведены

Comment: @Grundy видимо так проявляется "свободность" перевода :)

Comment: @alexolut ага! а вот и ответственный!!!

Comment: @Grundy отнюдь. Вся ответственность на авторе сообщения, т.е. Духе Николас Сообщества :)

Comment: @alexolut, вопрос общий, взял бы да перевел!

Comment: @Grundy вот, кстати, да. Вместо того, чтобы возмущаться в комментариях. Разрешаю приступать, товарищ Grundy!

Comment: @alexolut, а кто у нас тут сертифицированный переводчик товарищ @alexolut?!

Comment: @Grundy любой участник, с достаточной для взаимодействия на Мете репутацией, насколько я знаю.

Comment: В чате тоже есть свои ограничения, например пауза между star/unstar и период редактирования сообщения.

Comment: @AK зовите Grundy, он скажет [что](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6701/%d0%a0%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f%d0%bc-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b5#comment26246_6702) надо делать :)